# SQL Pivot Table with Additional Column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, pivot-table

I'm building a courier system using Codeigniter and Mysql for a small courier company. What I'm trying to do is to build a pivot table that will show the total payments made for a particular payment type for each waybill including the Grand Total.

I have this query now :

```
SELECT IFNULL( p.waybill_number,  'GrandTotal' ) AS Waybill, w.consignee, w.consignor,
       SUM( IF(       p.payment_terms =  'prepaid', p.amount, NULL ) ) AS Prepaid,
       SUM( IF( p.payment_terms =  'collect', p.amount, NULL ) ) AS Collect
FROM payment p JOIN
     waybill w
     ON p.waybill_number = w.waybill_number
GROUP BY p.waybill_number WITH ROLLUP
```

but this shows values for consignee and consignee in the last row. what i want is to show ONLY the GrandTotal for all "PREPAID" and "COLLECT" transactions in the very last row. I hope you can help.

Thanks in advance!!!

**UPDATE:::**
I've edited my query and it looks like this now...

```
SELECT
IFNULL(mw.waybill_number, 'GrandTotal') as Waybill,
CASE WHEN mw.waybill_number THEN c1.name ELSE NULL END as Consignee,
CASE WHEN mw.waybill_number THEN c2.name ELSE NULL END as Consignee,
SUM(IF(p.payment_terms = 'prepaid', p.amount, NULL)) as Prepaid,
SUM(IF(p.payment_terms = 'collect', p.amount, NULL)) as Collect
FROM manifest_waybill mw
JOIN waybill w
on w.waybill_number = mw.waybill_number
LEFT JOIN payment p
on p.waybill_number = mw.waybill_number
JOIN customer c1
on c1.customer_id = w.consignee
JOIN customer c2
on c2.customer_id = w.consignor
WHERE manifest_number = 103
GROUP BY mw.waybill_number WITH ROLLUP
```

the query runs but the result is not what i expected. this query repeats the value for consignee and consignor in every row.

**i want the result to be like this :**

waybill # | consignee | consignor |

1216415   |   A | B|

1216416   | C   | D|

1216417   |E    | F|

**what happens is :**

waybill # | consignee | consignor |

1216415   | E | F|

1216416   | E | F|

1216417   | E | F|

the value of the last row (121617) gets repeated in every row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, just use a `case` statement:

```
SELECT IFNULL(p.waybill_number,  'GrandTotal' ) AS Waybill,
       (CASE WHEN p.waybill_number IS NOT NULL THEN w.consignee END) as consignee,
       (CASE WHEN p.waybill_number IS NOT NULL THEN w.consignor END) as consignor,
       SUM(IF(p.payment_terms =  'prepaid', p.amount, NULL ) ) AS Prepaid,
       SUM(IF( p.payment_terms =  'collect', p.amount, NULL ) ) AS Collect
FROM payment p JOIN
     waybill w
     ON p.waybill_number = w.waybill_number
GROUP BY p.waybill_number WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: Wow!I'm really surprised on how quick your reply was. And it just worked perfectly!!! A million thanks to you!

Comment: Sir Gordon, could you explain what's happening with your query? I'm trying to understand what it's doing but i'm confused. It's working perfectly but i want to learn what's wrong with my query and why your query was right so i know what to do next time. Thanks!

Comment: The expression `p.waybill_number is not null` checks whether or not the row is the extra row added by `rollup`.  If so, then it puts in `NULL` instead of some other value.

Comment: i've updated my question.. what i wanted to do is to list all payments made in every waybills that are loaded in a manifest. show NULL if no payment made yet. please help me.